# Spring Integration: Imap, continuous remote service polling caused by attribute mail-filter-expression in imap-idle-channel-adapter

Tags: email, spring-integration, imap

I implemented a imap idle mail receiver with spring integration mail 4.2.6.
When, in the configuration of the receiver in the tag

```
 <mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter  mail-filter-expression="something"      ... >
```

i use the attribute "mail-filter-expression" this causes continuous ( about every second) polling of the remote mail service with this repeated message:

*10:29:21 INFO  o.s.i.mail.ImapMailReceiver - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]*

If i remove the attribute "mail-filter-expression" this continuos polling disappears.

I don't know if this is the desired behavior of the framework. 
My idea is to limit this comtinuos polling of the remote service, in fact i'm using the imap-**idle**-channel-adapter

this is my configuration of the receiver:

```
<mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter 
    id="mailAdapterMailInAccettazione"
    store-uri="imaps://...the url of the remote service 
    channel="emailsInAccettazioneDaLeggere" 
    auto-startup="true" 
    should-delete-messages="false"   
    should-mark-messages-as-read="false" 
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties" 
    mail-filter-expression="subject matches '(?i).*somenthing: .*'" > 
     <mail:transactional  synchronization-factory="syncFactoryAccettazione"/>
</mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
```

I want to cofigure the receiver in idle mode but using the mail-filter-expression attribute because i want to read only some emails.

**UPDATE** : after further investigation i discovered that the remote mail service doesn't support RECENT and USER flag:

*This email server does not support RECENT or USER flags*

So this is what was happening: 
mail-filter-expression caused messages to get filtered, but no message was flagged as RECENT = false. This caused 
continuous attempts to read the messages as all messages always appeared "
new"
.
I re implemented the flow not using the mail-filter-expression but filtering messages in subsequent channels

Comment: Any chances that you can upgrade to the latest `4.3.21`? `4.2.x` generation is in EOL and there really might be some inconsistency fixed in next versions.

Comment: i'll try to use the newer version as you suggested, hopefully not introducing some issues (it is an old app that i'm modifing). I'll write here if this solves the problem

Comment: I've updated to the 4.3.21 version of spring-integration-mail but sadly the continuos polling still persists